# rpy2 importr Error: Cannot import any packages

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, rpy2

I'm trying to import R packages into a python3 environment using rpy2, which has worked fine in the past. However, rpy2 has recently been raising an internal `TypeError: 'ExprSexpVector' object is not callable` error when I import any package using the importr function from rpy2. Even the most simple sample code from the rpy2 documentation fails to run (code below).

I've tried updating rpy2 to the most recent release via pip. Currently working with Python 3.7.3 and rpy2 3.0.5. Running on MacOS with Mojave 10.14.4 and R version 3.6.1 (fresh reinstall).

```py
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = importr("utils")
```

Instead of loading the r package, the second line raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/packages.py", line 492, in importr
    symbol_check_after=symbol_check_after)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/packages.py", line 204, in __init__
    self.__fill_rpy2r__(on_conflict=on_conflict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/packages.py", line 330, in __fill_rpy2r__
    .__fill_rpy2r__(on_conflict=on_conflict))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/packages.py", line 264, in __fill_rpy2r__
    rpyobj = conversion.rpy2py(riobj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/functools.py", line 827, in wrapper
    return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 207, in _rpy2py_sexpclosure
    return SignatureTranslatedFunction(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 163, in __init__
    formals.names,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/sexp.py", line 180, in names
    return embedded.globalenv.find('names')(self)
TypeError: 'ExprSexpVector' object is not callable
```

Running `$ python3 -m rpy2.situation` yields the following:

```
Python version:
3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 18:13:23) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)]
Looking for R's HOME:
    Environment variable R_HOME: None
    Calling `R RHOME`: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
    InstallPath in the registry: *** Only available on Windows ***
R version:
    In the PATH: R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
    Loading R library from rpy2: OK
Additional directories to load R packages from:
None
```

Comment: What does running python -m rpy2.situation in a terminal tell you ?

Comment: @lgautier I have added the results of your suggested command to the question.

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/566/rpy2-importr-error-cannot-import-any